# Setting TextView Typeface.NORMAL resets Typeface.SERIF

Tags: android

in my app, I have a textView where user can set both typeface and fontstyle. I am using this line to set Typeface.

```
tvQuoteTextSample.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
```

now, I am setting the font style using this line:

```
tvQuoteTextSample.setTypeface(tvQuoteTextSample.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);
```

this works fine. I can see the font has changed to Serif+Italic. The problem is when I am changing the font style to Normal, it is loosing the typeface.

```
tvQuoteTextSample.setTypeface(tvQuoteTextSample.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
```

The above line not only resets the italic to normal, it also resets the SERIF to default typeface.

How can I preserve the previous typeface and just change the font style to Normal?

I am using API: min sdk version = 17 and target version = 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply `Typeface.SERIF` with **Normal** style, then you should call:

```
tvQuoteTextSample.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

This should work fine as it sets the **typeFace** rather than updating it when used with `getTypeface()`.